# Timezone when serialize date with JsonOutput

Tags: groovy, timezone, iso8601

I have to serialize an object in json where the date have to be in iso-8601. The problem is that the timezone is +0000 and I would like the 'Z' instead. Any idea?

```
class MyClass{
 Date date = new Date()
 String string = "hello"
}   
def myClass = new MyClass()
log.error("Json->"+JsonOutput.toJson(myClass))
```

Output:

```
{"date":"2018-05-25T08:16:14+0000","string":"hello"}
```

Expected: 2018-05-25T08:16:14**Z**

Comment: Does it matter? According to the ISO 8601 standard `Z` and `+0000` are synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a good way of doing this is current versions of groovy and as per the following groovy JIRA ticket I suspect it is not possible:

[GROOVY-6854](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6854)

Reading up on that ticket it seems there is a workaround, but it involves modifying a private field which makes it quite brittle and un-elegant.

It seems that the groovy dev team has identified the lack of configurability as well since the upcoming 2.5.0 version of groovy now has a [new JsonGenerator class](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonGenerator.html) with which you can do the following:

```
import groovy.json.*

class MyClass { 
  Date now = new Date()
}

def generator = new JsonGenerator.Options()
    .dateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
    .build()

println generator.toJson(new MyClass())
```

which prints:

```
{"now":"2018-05-27T12:50:25Z"}
```

the accompanying [JsonGenerator.Options() builder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonGenerator.Options.html) gives a lot of flexibility for customizing json serialization.